# What are Launchpad packaging recipes and how can I use them?

Tags: development, launchpad, packaging, automation, recipe

As I understand it, packaging recipes are a way to automate packaging into a PPA from a bzr branch. What I'm not sure of is how to go about setting one up. I have read the documentation but for some reason it still leaves me a litte confused about what to do.

- What is the step by step process of setting up a recipe? (A 'hello world' example would be useful)
- What needs to go into the branch? (eg. debian/ directory)
- What do you write in the recipe text field and what does it all mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit lazy today, so I'll just give you two things worth reading and watching:

- [Launchpad source package recipes video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bG-SXNX9Ww)
- [Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes help](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes)

good luck!