# How to create a automatic PPA?

Tags: ppa, repository, launchpad, automatic, github

How can I create a PPA that automatically pulls changes from a git (hub) repository every time a new tag (release) is added, and then compiles the app?

Comment: I am not sure how to automate, you might ask the lxc team https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/daily "Those are daily builds of the master branch of git://github.com/lxc/lxc for all supported versions of Ubuntu." https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc - email members directly.

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35738/what-are-launchpad-packaging-recipes-and-how-can-i-use-them

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will need to maintain (install, configure) a `continuous integration system`. With proper configuration, such system can pull from git(hub) periodically or on every commit, it can build and package the software, and it can push it to a ppa and update the ppa metadata.

There are multiple CI systems, such as:

- [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) - you need to install this on your servers
- [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) - hosted solution that you can use online
- [teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) - there is a free and commercial versions that you need to install on your servers

For jenkins and teamcity, there may be some online providers too, but I have never looked for such.